# A better way to make a star pattern

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I got this code:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  output = "";
  for (var y = 0; y < 10 - i; y++) {
    output += "*";
  }
  console.log(output);
}

for (var x = 0; x <= 8; x++) {
  output2 = "";
  for (var z = 0; z < x + 2; z++) {
    output2 += "*";
  }
  console.log(output2);
}
```

the expected output would be a star pattern from 10 to 1 and from 2 to 10 again
Is there any better way to print this pattern???

Comment: "better way to print?" what do you mean?

Comment: a better code i mean

Comment: You could create a string with a bunch of stars in it, like `var stars = "**********";` and then use `stars.substr(0, n)` each time through the loop, where `n` is the length of that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decisions on what makes one algorithm better than another depends on who's deciding.

A somewhat different approach for your thoughts, using [`String.prototype.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) introduced in ES6:

```js
for( var i = 9, addend=-1; i<10; i+=addend) {
   console.log('*'.repeat(i));
   if( i==1)
      addend=1;
}
```

You may find it useful to review [String.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype) for additions from ECMAScript 2017 such as `padStart` and `padEnd` as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer like this, you could make a function that print the pattern from X to Y chars.

```js
function printCharPattern(chars, from, to) {
  const step = (from < to) ? 1 : -1;
  for (let it = from; it != to + step; it += step) {
    console.log(chars.substr(0, it));
  }
}

const stars = '**********';
printCharPattern(stars, 10, 1);
printCharPattern(stars, 2, 10);
```